# Non-linear regression line and its Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: argument "p" is missing, with no default error

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse

I have been trying to fit a non-linear regression line into my standard curve. However, I am getting the [following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k82G.jpg)

The main problem is that with the linear regression line I could use a simple command like:

```
stat_cor(label.y = c(825),
              label.x = c(0.88), 
          aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")))+
   stat_regline_equation(label.x=0.88, label.y=750)+
```

And the equation for the linear regression line with an `a`, and `b` values appear. In this case after using the following:

```
stat_smooth(method= "nlm", 
                formula = y~a*x/(b+x),
                method.args = list( start = c(a = 3.8, b = 1457.2)),
                se=FALSE)+
```

I am getting the above error.
You may ask where I got the `a`, and `b` values? I got them from:

```
nls(y~a*x/(b+x))
```

[That has shown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erdNq.jpg)

I do not know where I am making mistakes.

This is the entire code for my graph

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(data = STD, aes(x = Absorbance, y = STD)) +
  labs(title = "Quantifying PGD2 in cell culture lysates and its enzymatic reactions ",
       caption = "PGD2 ELISA")+
    geom_point(colour = "#69b3a2")+
    stat_smooth(method= "nlm", 
                formula = y~a*x/(b+x),
                method.args = list( start = c(a = 3.8, b = 1457.2)),
                se=FALSE)+
    xlab(expression(paste("%B/"~B[0])))+
    ylab(expression(paste("Prostaglandin"~ D[2], ~~ " MOX Concentration (pg/ml) ")))+
    
   theme(plot.background =  element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
         panel.background = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  
   theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0.01, "cm"))+
   theme(legend.position = c(0.77, .91),
         legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold.italic"),
         plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

That gives [the following outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POpBn.jpg)

And this is [DataUsed](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8fi7Xi8BskhLJWmLKNkgtgMYT0kA?e=Fypkyt)

Comment: Try with `list(p = c(a = 3.8, b = 1457.2)` as the argument for the starting values is called `p`. See `?nlm`.

Comment: I have tried this trick, and I am getting the error that says                                                 
` Warning: Computation failed in stat_smooth(): could not find function "f"`

Comment: At least an improvement. I just had another look. Probably you wanted method = "nls" instead of nlm in which case "start" would be the correct name for the argument. However even with that change stat_smooth will fail as your example data has only 5 obs. BTW: a warning is just a warning, but no error.

Comment: Exactly, it is just a warning but I really need the non-linear regression line as I have to fit the line to convert the sample absorbances to pg/ml PGD2. I know that there are at least 6 equations that could be used depending on the experiment you are doing and the science behind it, but, I am almost certain that this is the right equation `y~a*x/(b+x)` for my graph, I will double-check tho

Comment: Ok so, I have double-checked and the above equation is wrong. The equation that would best fit my graph is the four parametric logistic function: `y=d + a-d/1+ (x/c)^2` and after using such equation I am getting the following warning: `Warning: Computation failed in stat_smooth():
parameters without starting value in data: d`

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I have found a solution to my problem. I installed the `install.packages(drc)` in which the **four parametric function** is included. I set up my data `model <- drm(STD ~ Absorbance, fct = LL.4(), data = STD)`, then `plot(model)` , and I [got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOwm2.jpg)

I know it requires some alternations to make it look more professional, but it is just a cosmetic thing that I should be fine to do. Thank you @stefan for your time.